# Solve Directional Differential Equation: if $\nabla_vf(x)>(<)0$ for some $x$, then $\nabla_vf(x)>(<)0$ for all $x$.

Tags: functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, contest-math

$f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$

Find all class of functions $f$, satisfying that, for any given unit vector $v$, we have:

1) if $v\cdot\nabla f(x)>0$ for some $x$, then $v\cdot\nabla f(x)>0$ for all $x$, or

2)  if $\nabla_vf(x)<0$ for some $x$, then $\nabla_vf(x)<0$ for all $x$, or

3)  if $\nabla_vf(x)=0$ for some $x$, then $\nabla_vf(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Where $\nabla_vf=v\cdot\nabla f$ is the directional derivative.

(That is, we are exploring the iff condition of the condition given above.)

---

Linear function: $f(x)=\sum_i a_ix_i$ definitely works.

There are some other function I tested:

1) $f(x)=\sum_ia_i+\ln (b_i+x_i)$

2) $f(x)=\sum_i(a_i+x_i)^{b_i}+c_i$

Which does not work for this equation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "solve"? Those three statements do not hold in general, although they are true for linear functions, as you noted.

Comment: @angryavian updated. I hope it is now clearer

Comment: Still, what is your question? You've already found a whole class of functions that satisfy all three conditions.

Comment: @angryavian Yes I did find a class of function. But I what to find all possible classes. That is, I want to find the if and only if condition (functional form) for those three conditions.